# Unable to load class AndroidComponentsExtension after upgrading the Android Gradle Plugin 7.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-architecture-navigation, firebase-performance, android-safe-args

I recently downloaded [Android Studio Bumblebee](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#bumblebee) and it helpfully asked whether I wanted to upgrade to Android Gradle Plugin 7.1.0, the version that shipped alongside Android Studio Bumblebee.

After upgrading, I get a build error:

```
Unable to load class 'com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
```

And looking at the `idea.log` file, I see:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':main'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:103)
    ...
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':main'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/api/extension/AndroidComponentsExtension
    at androidx.navigation.safeargs.gradle.SafeArgsPlugin.apply(SafeArgsPlugin.kt:73)
    at androidx.navigation.safeargs.gradle.SafeArgsPlugin.apply(SafeArgsPlugin.kt:42)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension
```

Which means I can't run my app and I need to downgrade the AGP 7.0 to get things working again. How do I fix this and upgrade to Android Gradle Plugin 7.1.0?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

**Updating Navigation Safe Args**

These lines are the important ones to look at:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/api/extension/AndroidComponentsExtension
    at androidx.navigation.safeargs.gradle.SafeArgsPlugin.apply(SafeArgsPlugin.kt:73)
    at androidx.navigation.safeargs.gradle.SafeArgsPlugin.apply(SafeArgsPlugin.kt:42)
```

This indicates that the error is coming from the [Navigation Safe Args plugin](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args).

As per the [Android Gradle Plugin 7.1.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#navigation_safe_args_compatibility):

> AGP APIs that the Navigation Safe Args Gradle plugin depend on have been removed. **AGP 7.1 does not work with Navigation Safe Args versions 2.4.0-rc1 or 2.4.0**, but will work with versions 2.5.0-alpha01 and 2.4.1. In the meantime, as a workaround, you can use AGP 7.1 with a snapshot build of Navigation Safe Args, Navigation 2.5.0-SNAPSHOT. To use the snapshot build, follow the [snapshot instructions](https://androidx.dev/) with build id #8054565.

As [Navigation 2.4.1](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.4.1) is now available, you can upgrade to that version of Navigation to gain the fix:

> Backported from [Navigation `2.5.0-alpha01`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.5.0-alpha01): Safe Args now depends on Android Gradle Plugin version 7.0.4. This means that Navigation Safe Args will no longer be compatible with Android Studio versions prior to 7.0, but is now compatible with Android Gradle Plugin 7.1.0 and higher.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'

    // Update this line to use 2.4.1
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.1"
}
```

Note that you should always use the same version of the Navigation library as the Safe Args plugin (i.e., your app should also use Navigation 2.4.1): you should not try to use the Navigation 2.4.1+ Safe Args plugin with an earlier version of Navigation (such as 2.3.5).

**Note on Firebase Perf Plugin**

Note that you might see this same error when you are using:

```
classpath "com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.0"
```

With an `idea.log` of that states:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/api/extension/AndroidComponentsExtension
    at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.FirebasePerfClassVisitorFactory.registerForProject(FirebasePerfClassVisitorFactory.java:54)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.FirebasePerfPlugin.perform(FirebasePerfPlugin.java:145)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.FirebasePerfPlugin.lambda$apply$0(FirebasePerfPlugin.java:107)
```

As per the [Firebase Perf Plugin 1.4.1 Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#performance_gradle_plugin_v1-4-1):

> Migrated away from the deprecated Android Gradle plugin APIs.

So you should upgrade to 1.4.1:

```
classpath "com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.1"
```

Comment: yea, but the firebase perf plugin 1.4.* is not compatible with newest moshi. The bug is known, fix will be in Chipmunk. 1.3.5 worked fine until the Android Gradle Plugin 7.1.0. So, right now, it's impossible to use moshi with firebase perf plugin in newest "stable" AS. It's that great? https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/1463

Comment: @Jakoss - FWIW, [this comment on the Firebase issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3155#issuecomment-1021881709) seems to imply that Firebase Perf 1.3.2 _does_ work with both Moshi and AGP 7.1. Might be worth trying out.

Comment: Yes, it does work which is a little bit of a relief, but it's still very weird that we have to wait for chipmunk to work with newest firebase performance plugin. Using unstable channel is not an option for teams maintaining bigger apps

Comment: replacing 2.4.0 with 2.5.0-alpha01 worked for me. Thank you

Comment: For hilt issue, apply hilt_version = '2.40.5'

Comment: in my case bumping up hilt and firebase perf plugins version fixed the problem

Answer (score 16):

In my case, the problem was with **hilt** version. I've updated to the last `2.40.5` and it's work.

If you don't have **hilt** dependency in your project the best way to find a library that throws the exception during gradle sync it's to check **idea.log** file.

[image: android studio hint]

And find something like that.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/api/extension/AndroidComponentsExtension
    at dagger.hilt.android.plugin.HiltGradlePlugin.configureBytecodeTransformASM(HiltGradlePlugin.kt:257)
```

Have a good coding :)

Comment: In my case when, I had to upgrade both of hilt and navigation componnet version

Answer (score 13):

**Update:** the issue is now fixed in [AGP 7.1.2](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#7-1-0).

---

- Firebase perf plugin 1.4.1 will only work with AGP 7.1 if your project doesn't depend on any library that uses multi-release JARs, aka [MRJARs](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238).
- A popular dependency that uses MRJARs is [moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/1463).
- The root cause of the issue lies in the [Android Gradle Plugin](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/216160972).
- The Firebase Perf team made the following [statement](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3155#issuecomment-1026299821):

> Here are some updates:
>
> 1. AGP `v7.2.0-beta01` was made available last week and will work with the latest perf plugin `v1.4.1`.
> 2. AGP `v7.2 RC1` is scheduled to release on the 1st of March and AGP `v7.2` final is scheduled on the 9th of March.
>
> In the meantime, here are some workarounds worth trying out:
>
> 1. Use perf plugin `v1.3.5` with AGP `v6.8.3`. Perf plugin `v1.3.5` and below is not compatible with AGP `v7.0.0+`; in order for the perf plugin to be compatible with AGP `v7.0.0+`, we have to use the new transform API, which introduces the build failure where even if the perf plugin filters out classes in the `META-INF/` directory from instrumentation, AGP still tries to visit the class to collect information about it. However, AGP is working on a more permanent fix for this where we will have an option to filter out failed classes completely.
> 2. Wait until March 9 to integrate the latest perf plugin version and AGP.
> 3. Try a beta version of AGP with the latest perf plugin version and move to the production version after March 9th.

- Stack trace:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
    at ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/api/extension/AndroidComponentsExtension
    at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.FirebasePerfClassVisitorFactory.registerForProject(FirebasePerfClassVisitorFactory.java:54)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.FirebasePerfPlugin.perform(FirebasePerfPlugin.java:145)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.FirebasePerfPlugin.lambda$apply$0(FirebasePerfPlugin.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$2.execute(DefaultPluginManager.java:258)
    at ...
```

Comment: updating Firebase Performance plugin to 1.4.1 worked for me.

Comment: It will work only if your project doesn't depend on any library that uses MRJARs. I've updated the answer with more details about it.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this thing. Perfectly working for me

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
    id "com.google.dagger.hilt.android" version '2.41' apply false
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin' version '2.4.0' apply false // use this one
//    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.0" (will not work now)

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: You have to use the Plugin Id that you were previously using in the build.gradle of app folder (not the project build.gradle one)

Comment: Where did you get these version number?

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS The version numbers are same like previous versions of project's build.gradle dependency block

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade your gradle version, it will fix the issue

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
```

Gradle wrapper properties version

```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating Hilt to '2.40.5' and firebase:perf-plugin to '1.4.1' worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I faced issue on secrets-gradle-plugin. Initially I used version 2.0.1(latest). After I downgrade into 1.3.0. It worked for me.

In project's root build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:1.3.0'
}
```

In app-level build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
       id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I fixed the issue by downgrading the version of navigation to 2.3.5

    def nav_version = "2.3.5"
```

after testing, use navigation 2.4.0 and AGP 7.0.4 work fine

Comment: While this fixed the sync issue, this leads to other warnings due to deprecated API usages - `API 'BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'VariantProperties.applicationId'.
It will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
For more information, see TBD.` - I particularly like the 'see TBD' part of that message, indicating that this is likely dangerous territory that could also break at any point.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to update Maps plugin..

[image: Updated Maps Plugin]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your navigation safeargs version to latest and everything will be fine. It worked for me. Here is [the link ] (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation "Navigation safeargs google documentation")! to get latest safeargs version.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32774842)

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem implementing Hilt in my project. I found out it was a plugin compatibility issue, just updating to the latest version fixed the issue.

> Strangely, the IDE didn't signal that there was a newer version
> available, so I had to search manually.

**in the project's build.gradle:**

I changed this line:

```
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.35"
```

for this one:

```
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.45"
```

problem solved.

full file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradleplugin:2.5.3"
    classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.45"
   }
}

plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.21' apply false

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to build.gradle(project) and add the following dependency:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.6"
```

Now try again.
Done