# How to add classpath in new version of Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

I updated my android studio version to bumblebee version.
Now I want add navigation component to my project.
I want add classpath to gradle, but this file gradle has been changed and I don'y know how can I add this.

I want add this        `classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")` to gradle files!

My project gradle file is :

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How can I add this classpath to application gradle ?!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In the latest version in February 2022 doesn't need to add `buildscript` anymore just add the id in `build.gradle` for project. It will be like this in `build.gradle` for project:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false

    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.4.1' apply false
    // classpath are changed, so no need to add classpath anymore just the id and the version
}
```

Don't forget add the id again in the `build.gradle` module,

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. but how can I find this ids ? for example dagger-hilt

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#setup

From there the id was you put in `build.gradle` module, the id is `dagger.hilt.android.plugin`, hope it works.

Comment: i tryed but dagger not working

Comment: For Dagger Hilt, add `id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.41' apply false` to project build.gradle file

and    `id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'` to app build.gradle file as usual

Comment: @feigo808 where did you find this?

Answer (score 25):

They haven't talked about in the release docs but  manually add a buildscript block above the plugins block then inside the buildscript block add a depedencies block.

like this:

```
buildscript {

        dependencies {

              classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.0")

                     }
       }


plugins {
      id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0-rc01' apply false
      //......
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but show me this error : `Unable to load class 'com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension.`
'

Comment: take a look at this SO [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70857476/unable-to-load-class-androidcomponentsextension-after-upgrading-the-android-grad)

Comment: It helped, its a correct Solution to add classpath.

Answer (score 4):

So they mentioned that in the build.Gradle file as top-level comment And I saw it as a bad practice
don't mention it below that
1- open your build.Gradle (app module) scroll to the top until you see that comment
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

then take this code As copy put it this line is[image] builtin comment
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

```
dependencies {

    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:lasted-version"

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You dont need buildscript.You can add as 'id' inside plugin component.I was face with it in hilt entegration.Here is the sample
Top level gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.43.2' apply false
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And second level(project level gradle)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
}....


dependencies {

.....
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.43.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.43.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can add class path directly in the top Level Build.gradle file as follows.

Code
[image]

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.5.3"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
}
```

This is sample for adding safe args for Navigation component as suggested in the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args)