# Android Studio Bumblebee unable to use Safeargs

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I have recently updated my android studio to Stable Bumblebee version . I want to use Nav controller with safe args in my new android project .But as the Gradle plugin has changed to 7.1.0 , I am confused that where to add classpath dependency of safe args.
Can you please help ?

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70376213/new-build-gradle-in-android-studio-bumblebee-2021-1-1-beta-5-error-adding-depe

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin' version '2.5.0-alpha01' apply false